# How to download captcha from a page?

Tags: python, html, asp.net, parsing, web-scraping

The website from which I want to download the captcha is https://academicscc.vit.ac.in/student/

I am trying to make the login for this website automatic using python. And therefore, want to autofill the captcha.

Here is the HTML code for the captcha 

`<img src="captcha.asp" id="imgCaptcha" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondrag="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">`

If I open `captcha.asp` to download the image, the captcha changes to a new one.

Is there any way I could download the captcha?

> I was thinking to implement this using selenium to simulate `'Ctrl+S'` but I'm not sure how would I control the save dialog box.

Comment: The purpose of captcha style security is to ensure that a human is logging in and not an automated program (like you are attempting). So the whole captcha system structure is build around that security concept. So normally its not really possible to do so.

Comment: @AhsN This is my project for this semester. Plus, if you were to open the mentioned website you would know how old their captcha system is.

Comment: Next question is "how to read captcha string" ? Download captcha image is easy, "how to handle related session ?"...

Comment: @dsgdfg, use Google's tesseract library to convert captcha to string. Btw, can you help me out for downloading the captcha for the given link?

Comment: Every `web module` save page contents to anywhere, but i don't know where ? Ask google "python selenium where page image" but some image triggered  from javascript, "how to run javascript commands ?"